# Animated gif is not displayed on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, animated-gif

There is an animated gif :

```
  ...
  <div id="loading" class="loading">
    <div style="text-align:center"><img src="loading.gif"/></div>
  </div>
  ...
```

css :

```
.loading {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

When I run the application on `Mozilla Firefox` version 52 then the animated gif is showing successfully , but it does not show on `Google Chrome` version 61 !

So what is wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried in a clean Google Chrome instance? (without extra plugins) https://superuser.com/questions/254579/how-to-open-google-chrome-with-extensions-disabled-turned-off

Answer (score 0):

It might be some Chrome extension prevents animated gif from loading.

Comment: how to know those extensions and how to remove them ?

Comment: Navigate to URL chrome://extensions/

Comment: After navigating to the url you gave then it showed : `Boo… You have no extensions :-(` ; so what else cause the problem ?